# How to get part name in LaTeX ?

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, parts

Actually I am using the `fancyhdr` package, and trying to put the current part name in the right header.

I know that `\rightmark` and `\leftmark` are used to represent the current section and chapter heading respectively, but I can not find anything similar to represent the part name.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That would depend on what type of "part" you are refering to, `\chaptername`, `\sectionname`, `\thepage`, `\thesection`, `\thechapter`, etc... See [this link](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Page_Layout) for details.

EDIT: In light of your comment, [this thread](http://www.tug.org/pipermail/macostex-archives/2004-September/009840.html) seems to be discussing a solution (*note:* there is a typo, it must be `\renewcommand{\part}...`, i.e. a backslash must be added):

> For using the parts, you can do the
>   following:
>
> ```
> \let\Oldpart\part
> \newcommand{\parttitle}{}
> \renewcommand{part}[1]{\Oldpart{#1}\renewcommand{\parttitle}{#1}}
> ```
>
> and then use \parttitle in the header.
>
> Another alternative is to use the
>   `titlesec` package which provides
>   commands like `\partmark` that you can
>   use.

Comment: I am refering to \part - http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Document_Structure#Sectioning_Commands

Comment: thank you very much - the solution from the thread works!

Comment: Note that this redefinition doesn't support the optional argument of `\part`.

Comment: I just installed titlesec for this. However `\partmark` doesn't do anything for me. I checked their [documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/titlesec/titlesec.pdf) and cannot find the phrase `\partmark`.

Comment: Of course the third line should start with `\renewcommand{\part}` (missing `\ ` in front of `part`).

Comment: To avoid a bug when using this together with `\AtBeginPart`, the last line could rather be: `\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\renewcommand{\parttitle}{#1}\Oldpart{#1}}`

Comment: I personally used `\renewcommand{\part}[1]{\pagebreak\Oldpart{#1}\renewcommand{\parttitle}{#1}}`. Without it, the last page before the new part got the wrong heading.

Answer (score 17):

Putting the part title into the header is not common, therefore there are no default macros for this.

You could redefine the `\part` macro to save its argument to e.g. a `\parttitle` macro which then can be used in the custom defined headers:

```
\newcommand*\parttitle{}
\let\origpart\part
\renewcommand*{\part}[2][]{%
   \ifx\\#1\\% optional argument not present?
      \origpart{#2}%
      \renewcommand*\parttitle{#2}%
   \else
      \origpart[#1]{#2}%
      \renewcommand*\parttitle{#1}%
   \fi
}
```

Comment: Note that this solution (though it works very well in LaTeX) leads to an error on conversion with pandoc (v2.3.1) to docx (cf. [my question on Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52703315/pandoc-produces-error-from-tex-to-docx-on-redefinition-of-part) ). Benjamin's solution converts fine with pandoc.

Answer (score 13):

In the KOMA-classes `\part` executes a `\partmark` command which you could use to set either `\rightmark` or `\leftmark` to the part title.

But as `\part` always generates a new page and you probably need the header only on the next page you can also do something simple like this:

```
\newcommand\partcontent{}
...

\part{Blub}
\renewcommand\partcontent{Blub}
```

and then use `\partcontent` in the header.

Comment: +1 for `\partmark`, which is not mentioned in the KOMA-script manual.

Answer (score 9):

You could use `\markboth{left headmark}{right headmark}%` to put the title into the header. Some classes provide a `\partmark` command for it, which you could redefine for calling `\markboth` inside.

Standard classes don't provide `\partmark`. For example, `book.cls` even calls `\markboth{}{}` to remove the header entries when `\part` is called. You could redefine `\part` or hook somehow into it.

I would choose an extended class such as those of KOMA-Script instead of reinventing the wheel every time a new feature is required.

Deferring `\markboth` to the following page could be solved using the [`afterpage`](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) package:

```
\afterpage{\markboth{}{part title}}
```

Answer (score 9):

I couldn't find a macro that saves the part's title, so I used the [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) package to patch the internals within the `\part` command to do that.  Then you just take that save macro and put it wherever.

```
\documentclass{report}
\title{part name in right mark}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter
% patch \@part[#1]{#2} and \@spart (see the class file) to save the part name
\pretocmd{\@part}{\gdef\parttitle{#1}}{}{}
\pretocmd{\@spart}{\gdef\parttitle{#1}}{}{}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\rightmark}{\parttitle}


\begin{document}


\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\part{First part}

\chapter{first chapter}

\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\chapter{second chapter}

\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\part{Second part}

\chapter{third chapter}

\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\chapter{fourth chapter}

\lipsum\lipsum\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: a more elegant solution... the marked answer was causing a few problems in another document

Comment: @umar: It is perfectly admissible to "un-accept" an answer and accept another one instead.

Comment: No works in book class, just appears "#1" ... at least in my case

Comment: @juanuni: The `book` class might have a different implementation of `\part`.  My patching of auxiliary macros was specific to how `report` did it.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang I saw that ...

Comment: You have to add an empty parttitle for the beginning `\gdef\parttitle{}`, then it works also in the `book` class

Answer (score 0):

I would like to expand a little on Martin Scharrer's answer. If you also need the chapter number, you can do this:

```
\directlua{partcount = 0}
\newcommand*\partnumber{}
\newcommand*\parttitle{}
\let\origpart\part
\renewcommand*{\part}[2][]{%
   \ifx\\#1\\% optional argument not present?
      \origpart{#2}%
      \renewcommand*\parttitle{#2}%
   \else
      \origpart[#1]{#2}%
      \renewcommand*\parttitle{#1}%
   \fi
   \directlua{partcount = partcount + 1}%
   \renewcommand*\partnumber{\directlua{tex.sprint(partcount)}}%
}
```

It defines the `\partnumber` command, to get the part number, as well as the `\parttitle` command.

This is using [LuaTex](http://www.luatex.org/), but something similar is probably also possible in plain LaTeX.