# fancyhdr: putting part in fancyhdr

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, parts

For my dissertation I've redefined `\thechapter` as `\thepart` because I'm only using parts, sections and subsections. With the code below I get the section as the right header but nothing on the left. How do I get the part to appear on the left?

```
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thepart}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\parttitle.\ #1}{}}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection.\ #1}{}}
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyhead[L]{\textit{\leftmark}} 
\fancyhead[R]{\textit{\rightmark}}
\renewcommand{\cfoot}{\thepage}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to get part name in LaTeX ?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13387/how-to-get-part-name-in-latex)

Comment: @lockstep There are other approaches than thru `\partname`, as you can see in my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code does the job. It redefines LaTeX internal command `\@part` to call `\markboth`. Package `lipsum` is there to provide some dummy text.

As well, I cleaned the code:

- You don't need to redefine `\sectionmark` nor `\chaptermark`.
- There is no command `\parttitle`, it's `\partname`.
- You should use `\fancyfoot` and don't redefine `\cfoot`.

The code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\thepart}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{} 
\fancyhead[L]{\textit{\leftmark}} 
\fancyhead[R]{\textit{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot{}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}
\makeatletter
\let\old@part\@part
\def\@part[#1]#2{\old@part[#1]{#2\markboth{\MakeUppercase{\partname.\ #1}}{}}}
\makeatother

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\part{PP}

\section{SS}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.  I redefined \sectionmark so that it was in lowercase but your changes worked perfectly.  Unfortunately on the first page of each part (the page after the separating page) the \sectionmark no longer appears, even though it does on the subsequent pages.  I was wondering if you know how to fix this?

Comment: I modifed the code. Only the longest line of the code got changed.