# fancyhdr: How get part on even and chapter on odd pages

Tags: header-footer, chapters, fancyhdr, double-sided, parts

I am trying to use `fancyhdr` to set the part no. and name on my left pages and chapter no and name on the right pages.

My document is

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside,openright,bibliography=totocnumbered]{scrbook}
```

I use the following code (which looks wrong and doesn't work too well):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}

\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth% 
  {\color[gray]{.0}\thepart. #1}{}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright%
  {\color[gray]{.0}\thechapter.\ #1}}
```

The effect is: I get the part alright but the chapter only makes it to the head as long as I haven't used a section. Once there's a section in my text, it seems to overrule the chapter.

Comment: Perhaps [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/48410) is helpful, or [this one](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13387).

Comment: Hi Thorsten, Thanks for the links. However, I had looked at both questions before posting and they couldn't solve my problem (which is with chapter rather than part).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to redefine `\sectionmark` to do nothing (and also to clear the fields):

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth
  {\color[gray]{.0}\thepart. #1}{}}

\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright
  {\color[gray]{.0}\thechapter.\ #1}}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
```

However, I would put formatting instructions into `\fancyhead` and not in the `\markright` and `\markboth` commands:

```
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[RE]{\color[gray]{0}\leftmark}
\fancyhead[LO]{\color[gray]{0}\rightmark}
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\partmark}[1]{\markboth{\thepart. #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markright{\thechapter.\ #1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
```

Comment: Also, thanks for not just posting the solution but for explaining it well!

Comment: Looks easy, but what I am getting for a book class is: ! LaTeX Error: Command \partmark undefined. Any clue?