# LyX: How to get the Part name to print in headers

Tags: header-footer, lyx, parts

I have a LyX article, structured with Parts -> Sections -> Subsections, and I want to print the Part name in the document header.

I am trying to get the part name with the following command, but it prints "Part"

```
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \partname}
```

I have also read & tried [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13387/how-to-get-part-name-in-latex) but my document doesn't compile.

How can I simply get the part name within the LaTeX Preamble?

Comment: The [question your link to and its answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13395/10102) do provide the solution. What is the error you get when compiling?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: @Speravir In the [first post of your suggestion](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13395) there is `\renewcommand{part}...` but not `\renewcommand{\part}...`. It is a typo, isn't it?

Comment: @e-birk Yes, it is. I added a remark.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. In "Document settings..." under "Page Layout" change the heading style to "fancy".
2. It seems that you want the part title in the header and not `\partname`, which will usually print the word "Part" or a translation of it. Hence, considering the [suggested thread](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13387/how-to-get-part-name-in-latex) and *correcting a typo* - `{part}` should be `{\part}` - we put

   ```
   \let\Oldpart\part
   \newcommand{\parttitle}{}
   \renewcommand{\part}[1]{\Oldpart{#1}\renewcommand{\parttitle}{#1}}
   ```

   into the LaTeX Preamble.
3. At the beginning of your document or from where every you want to start it as TeX code/ERT (or for global setting, in the LaTeX Preamble) we write

   ```
   \fancyhead[LE,RO]{\slshape \parttitle}
   ```