# TOC Problems: Every pages appear word "CONTENTS"

Tags: table-of-contents, header-footer, lyx

I got the problems with TOC, by the way. When I start to put TOC in my book, after that in every pages header appear word "CONTENTS" with capitalize font. I don't know how to edit or custom it. I try to finding documentation and FAQ at Lyx.com but they explanation not enough to solving my problem. I just getting stuck after while. What should I do for solve this problem? if could I want rename these header by chapter name like "BAB I".

Thanks in advance.

FYI: I use document class: book.

Here my problem, appear words CONTENT in header:

[appear words CONTENT in header http://www.zakariyasoewardi.co.uk/sandbox/img/Lyx-error-1.jpg](http://www.zakariyasoewardi.co.uk/sandbox/img/Lyx-error-1.jpg)
[appear words CONTENT in header http://www.zakariyasoewardi.co.uk/sandbox/img/Lyx-error-2.jpg](http://www.zakariyasoewardi.co.uk/sandbox/img/Lyx-error-2.jpg)

Comment: I assume `BAB II` is a `Chapter*`? What would you want your headers to look like other than displaying `CONTENTS`?

Comment: No, BAB II is a Part*. I want custom header by chapter name like "BAB I". Depending on where the pages are still in a chapter.

Comment: Can you show us a complete document with this behaviour, please! Make it something short that only has that table of contents and then some new chapter where you don't get the header you expect.

Comment: sorry @pst I think I've enough clear to explain my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason for `CONTENTS` in the header stems from the `\tableofcontents` macro in the `book` document class/[`book.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/book.cls):

```
\newcommand\tableofcontents{%
    \if@twocolumn
      \@restonecoltrue\onecolumn
    \else
      \@restonecolfalse
    \fi
    \chapter*{\contentsname
        \@mkboth{%
           \MakeUppercase\contentsname}{\MakeUppercase\contentsname}}%
    \@starttoc{toc}%
    \if@restonecol\twocolumn\fi
    }
```

The above is executed when you Insert > List / TOC > Table of Contents in LyX. Note how the ToC is inserted as a `\chapter*`, with `both` the left and right `mark`s being set in `Uppercase` as `\contentsname` (which defaults to `Contents`, by the way).

By default, numbered parts (`\part`) clear the headings, while unnumbered parts (`\part*`) don't. That's exactly why you see the header continuing without change from the ToC.

To adjust the headers automatically with the use of your sectional unit, switch from `Part*` to `Chapter` and use an appropriate package to adjust (in the Document > Settings... > LaTeX Preamble) the formatting to suit your needs. Alternatively, you can insert an ERT containing

```
\markboth{BAB I}{BAB I}
```

manually after a `Part*` to update the header accordingly.

Comment: For more specific detail about automation, you need to supply us with a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) that you exported from LyX showing at least the ToC and a single `Part*`.

Comment: Thanks, for temporary it's answer my problem. I appreciate for that.

Comment: I've had a similar issue with `\chapter*` for un-numbered chapters - this doesn't set the marks either. After reading this answer, I made this command `\def\chapternotnumbered#1{\chapter*{#1}\markboth{#1}{#1}}` which seems to work ok although I wouldn't be surprised if I later find I've broken something else with it :D

Answer (score 1):

I don't use Lyx, but as you say you're using `\part*` instead of `\chapter*` this is probably the cause your header isn't updated correctly. The text in the headers is defined in the commands `\leftmark` and `\rightmark`, which in a `book` by default use the last known chapter and section title respectively.

Since the table of contents inserts a chapter header, and after that only `part*` commands are issued, the last known chapter title remains `Contents`, which is converted to `CONTENTS` by `\leftmark`. Parts are intended to group sets of chapters together, usually with only a small description that's not filed under a new chapter, and so I think it is better to use `chapter` commands if that is what you write.

If you don't like the way the chapter titles are typeset it is better to alter that configuration, than to misuse other commands. With TeX you should write what you mean in a document, and not use another command that seems to provide a better looking result straight away (that's more the MS Word philosophy ;) ).

Comment: Honestly, I'm getting confuse with these problem. But I got reference in some forum, where they use 'fancyhdr' so they can edit '\leftmark' and '\rightmark' manually. Should I use that too? how that's work, I'm using Lyx with GUI and I don't understand with script except ERT a little.

Comment: I don't know how to do it with LyX, but if you really want to stick with using parts as chapters I suppose you could redefine `\leftmark` to use the part title. To get a `\parttitle`/`\partmark` command see for example [this answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13395/46598). `fancyhdr` is mostly used (as the name suggests) to design the headers, and still should use `\leftmark` to get the chapter title, unless you redefine it manually.

Answer (score 0):

Taking a lead from Werners answer,

"Alternatively, you can insert an ERT containing

```
\markboth{BAB I}{BAB I}
```

manually after a Part* to update the header accordingly."

I just used `\markboth{}{}` to get rid of the "CONTENTS" on the top left of my book. I used it right after where I inserted my TOC. Worked like magic!!

Thanks everyone ...