# Display section on first chapter page when that page number is odd

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, double-sided, report

Using `\documentclass[twoside]{report}`, I would like the following headers:

- on the left, for even pages `Part Title: Chapter Title`
- on the right, for odd pages `Section Title`

In the MWE, I'm mostly getting what I want, based on these questions:

- [How to get part name in LaTeX ?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13387/how-to-get-part-name-in-latex/13395#13395)
- [Why doesn't \pagestyle{empty} work on the first page of a chapter?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19738/why-doesnt-pagestyleempty-work-on-the-first-page-of-a-chapter/19741#19741)

However, as seen on pages 3 and 7, when a chapter begins on an odd-numbered page, the section title doesn't appear in the header. Given the behavior on page 6, headings are working for even-numbered chapter start pages.

How do I get the section title to appear in the header on odd-numbered pages where a chapter begins?

**MWE**

```
    \documentclass[twoside]{report}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{blindtext}
    \usepackage{etoolbox}

    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13395/56480
    \let\Oldpart\part
    \newcommand{\parttitle}{}
    \renewcommand{\part}[1]{
        \Oldpart{#1}
        \renewcommand{\parttitle}{#1}   
    }

    \pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\parttitle: #1}{}}
    \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

    \fancyhead[RO]{\rightmark}       
    \fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}  
    \fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

    %https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19741/56480
    \patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{fancy}{}{}

    \begin{document}

    \tableofcontents
    \part{First Part}
    \chapter{First Chapter}
    \blindtext[1]
    \section{First Section}
    \blindtext[5]
    \section{Second Section}
    \blindtext[7]
    \chapter{Second Chapter}
    \blindtext[1]
    \section{Third Section}
    \blindtext[2]
    \chapter{Third Chapter}
    \blindtext[1]
    \section{Fourth Section}
    \blindtext[5]\end{document}
```

Comment: This is not good typography: headers are provided to help you find at which place you are in the document you're reading. On the first page of  a chapter,  this information is totally redundant.

Comment: @Bernard: You're right. When posting a question, it seems we find ourselves caught between the tension between an over-complicated MWE, or an MWE that captures the functional concerns of the behavior, but doesn't necessarily satisfy the typographical concerns of every reader. It seems either case inspires ire. Meanwhile, my question remains unanswered.

Comment: this is a puzzler.  i don't see any reason *in the file `report.cls`* for this to be happening.  one can see from the heading on the toc page that running head text is inserted, and if the first `\chapter` is changed to `\chapter*`, it gets text too.  so there is something different between `\@chapter` and `\@schapter` that isn't obvious.  the next place to look, it seems, is to `latex.ltx`, but that makes no sense (and also, i haven't got time to dig through that just now).  i'll take another look later, but maybe this clue will help someone else.

Comment: I wasn't angry. Just wanted to draw your attention to this point. That said, what do you  mean with `part name`: the word ‘part’, or  the part title? All this should be easy to do with `titlesec/titleps` ‘ at least for standard classes.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: Thank you for taking a look. I wasn't sure where to investigate, let alone where the trail might lead. It might be that messing with the headers in this way will end in _TeXnicalities_.

Comment: @Bernard: Tone is sometimes difficult to interpret over the Internet. I think I'm referring to the part title in my MWE, but that turns up just fine on the even pages. I would like to be able to display the current section title (for example, as it appears on page 5) on chapters that begin on an odd-numbered page.

Comment: Every time \ps@fancy executes, it redefines \chaptermark and \sectionmark.  The is also a \if@fancyplain check in things like \headrule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mark command sets three variables: `\topmark` (last mark of the previous page), `firstmark` (first mark on the current page) and `\botmark` (last mark on the current page). `\rightmark` uses the `\firstmark` set by `\markright` or the second argument of `\markboth`. On a chapter page the first call of `\markboth` is done by `\chapter` with an empty second argument to reset the header entry.

If it is alright to use the last section occurring on a page you could define a command `\rightbotmark` using `\botmark` instead `\firstmark`.

```
\makeatletter
\providecommand*{\rightbotmark}{\expandafter\@rightmark\botmark\@empty\@empty}
\makeatother
```

and then

```
\fancyhead[RO]{\rightbotmark}
```

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}


%http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/13395/56480
\let\Oldpart\part
\newcommand{\parttitle}{}
\renewcommand{\part}[1]{
    \Oldpart{#1}
    \renewcommand{\parttitle}{#1}   
}

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\rightbotmark}{%
    \expandafter\@rightmark\botmark\@empty\@empty
}
\makeatother

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{\parttitle: #1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}

\fancyhead[RO]{\rightbotmark}
\fancyhead[LE]{\leftmark}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

%http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/19741/56480
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{fancy}{}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\part{First Part}
\chapter{First Chapter}
\blindtext[1]
\section{First Section}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Second Section}
\blindtext[7]
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\blindtext[1]
\section{Third Section}
\blindtext[2]
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\blindtext[1]
\section{Fourth Section}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation about what goes on with the `\mark` command. I'm accepting this answer because I found it to be the most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with `titlesec` and `etoolbox`. We have to redefine `\part` from within titlesec:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\usepackage[pagestyles,  outermarks,  clearempty]{titlesec}%
\titleformat{\part}[display]{\filcenter\bfseries\Huge}{\partname~\thepart}{3ex}{}[\thispagestyle{empty}]
\newpagestyle{mypagestyle}{
\settitlemarks{part, chapter, section}
\headrule
\sethead[\parttitle:   \chaptertitle][][]{}{}{\sectiontitle}
\setfoot{}{\thepage}{}
}
\pagestyle{mypagestyle}
\patchcmd{\chapter}{plain}{mypagestyle}{}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents\thispagestyle{plain}
\part{First Part}
\chapter{First Chapter}%\thispagestyle{mypagestyle}
\blindtext[1]
\section{First Section}
\blindtext[5]
\section{Second Section}
\blindtext[7]
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\blindtext[1]
\section{Third Section}
\blindtext[2]
\chapter{Third Chapter}
\blindtext[1]
\section{Fourth Section}
\blindtext[5]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the alternative using `titlesec`. I like that syntax, and I'll be looking at using that package in the future.

Comment: I draw your attention to the fact that `titleps` is incompatible with `fancyhdr`. Personally, I find the former more easy to use (no need to fiddle with marks).